# Android: create barcode image and display in imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, barcode, zxing

My Goal: To generate a PDF417 format 2D- barcode and display it in an ImageView in my application.

I am using the ZXing2.1 library's core.jar and j2se.jar.

Following code is trying to create a barcode and display it in an imageView.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    try {

        Writer writer;
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = null;
        writer = new PDF417Writer();
        bitMatrix = writer.encode("123456789", BarcodeFormat.PDF_417, 580, 150);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
        InputStream decodedInput=new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) byteArrayOutputStream).toByteArray());
        Drawable d = BitmapDrawable.createFromStream(decodedInput, "src");
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        System.out.println("PDF417 Code Generated.");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

When I execute the code, I get this error:

```
07-01 08:42:13.148: ERROR/dalvikvm(1508): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage
07-01 08:42:13.178: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(MatrixToImageWriter.java:54)
    at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(MatrixToImageWriter.java:99)
    at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(MatrixToImageWriter.java:91)
    at com.example.untitled.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The reason seems obvious. But now I dont know how to write the image data to a stream from a bitMatrix.

Kindly suggest a solution. I will appreciate pointers, if any.

Note: I have gone through a lot of stack overflow solutions and the ones on the web. Most of them are around ZXing integration and do not cater my specific problem. Redirect me to appropriate solution, in case it hasn't lured my attention.

Also I would like to know an elegant way of handling this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The whole java.awt.* framework isn't part of the Android SDK,
>   including BufferedImage, and hence not supported by the emulator or
>   physical devices. Android has its own implementation for loading and
>   rendering graphics.

[Referance here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132589/2345913)

As far as solution to problem [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14207326/2345913).. It uses [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) class to aid in creating Barcode..

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I did actually find a solution. I wanted to understand the use of hints and the encoding type. What value does it provide? Is it OK to skip that part?