# Communicating with an xbee module using Android 3+ phone

Tags: android, xbee, ftdi

I want to connect my Xbee module to my android phone and communicate with it by sending AT commands.

I do know of the USB host facility provided by Android phones, but I do not know how to send data to it.

I have the java-Xbee API and I am able to talk to the Xbee using my computer but since my project involves using the Android OS, any help on this topic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Google Code Page](https://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/#Overview), the java-Xbee API requires Java >= 5 and RXTX.
 Considering those two requirements:-

1. RXTX on android is **not an out of the box lib** and [may require some hacking](http://v-lad.org/projects/gnu.io.android/) which may or may not work.
2. I'm not a Java VM expert, but i know desktop OS JVMs work differently from Dalvik.
   How well would Dalvik run code developed for JVM? Here is a nice [StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374477/android-javac-vs-dalvik) discussing the two.

Faced with the above challanges, are you brave enough to boldly go where no man has gone before?
Could you also consider the following well documented and supported approaches:-

1. [Ytai Ben-Tsvi](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki) & Sparkfun's [IOIO-OTG](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11343)
   [Saves you the headache writing android 3.1+ USB host code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) and thus allows you to use cheaper phones that run droids 1.5 to 2.3 ([without hacking the latter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.android.usbhostcontroller&hl=sw)).
2. Digi's [WiFi to Xbee](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-wi-fi)
   Allows you to link your android phone (or any other programmable wifi enabled computer) to your device over the internet.